# Parse EPUB container with Ruby and LibXNL

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, epub

I have Ruby code which is intended to look inside an extracted EPUB
file, find the location of the OPF metadata file and return it.  The
path to the OPF file (relative to the root of the EPUB) is written
to an XML file found in META-INF/container.xml.  The file content is
as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<container version="1.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:container">
   <rootfiles>
      <rootfile full-path="content.opf" media-type="application/oebps-package+xml"/>
   </rootfiles>
</container>
```

I'm using LibXML and XPath to extract the root file path.  The problem
is that LibXML reports that my XPath expression is invalid.  The same
expression works when using Python and LXML.  The relevant portion of
my code is below.

```
require 'libxml'
include LibXML
container = File.join("META-INF", "container.xml")
tree = XML::Document.file(container)
rootfile = tree.find_first("//{urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:container}rootfile")['full-path']
```

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Comment: Perhaps LibXML cannot handle a default namespace in this way? What happens if you search for `"//rootfile"`?

Comment: @Mathias It returns nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that the way LibXML handles default namespaces is different from lxml. Try to define an alias (i.e. a prefix) for the namespace.

```
require 'libxml'
include LibXML
container = File.join("META-INF", "container.xml")
tree = XML::Document.file(container)
tree.root.namespaces.default_prefix = 'opf'
rootfile = tree.find_first("//opf:rootfile")['full-path']
```

Alternatively, use `find_first` with a second argument, containing namespace declarations:

```
require 'libxml'
include LibXML
container = File.join("META-INF", "container.xml")
tree = XML::Document.file(container)
rootfile = tree.find_first("//opf:rootfile", "opf:urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:container)['full-path']
```

But then you need to know this namespace in advance and hard-code it. Find more info on working with namespaces [here](http://xml4r.github.io/libxml-ruby/rdoc/classes/LibXML/XML/XPath.html).

Comment: That did it.  As an aside, the full-path dictionary key is a string not a symbol as I thought.  I

Comment: @HadenPike Glad it works. Please consider accepting this answer if it solved your problem - as you did for your previous questions. Thanks!

Comment: Knew I forgot something. My bad.